# How can I integrate Admob mediation in an Adobe Air app?

Tags: air, admob, ane

I want to use Admob mediation on an Air app.

Is there any ane for this or can I use any ane and then just change settings in Admob account ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To integrate Admob in your AIR APP, you can use :

**Free ANEs :**

- [admob-for-flash](https://github.com/lilili87222/admob-for-flash) : https://github.com/lilili87222/admob-for-flash.
- [Advertising-ANE](https://github.com/digicrafts/Advertising-ANE) : https://github.com/digicrafts/Advertising-ANE.

You can find some other projects on [github](https://github.com/search?q=admob+ane).

**Commercial ANEs :**

- [AdMob](https://www.milkmanplugins.com/admob-air-ane) from [milkmanplugins.com](https://www.milkmanplugins.com) : [ActionScript API](https://www.milkmanplugins.com/as3doc/adMob/com/milkmangames/nativeextensions/AdMob.html), and how to use it [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/admob-ane-android.html).

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I actually "want to use Admob mediation on an Air app", but don't know how. Note: Admob mediation, not regular Admob, which is working well. I am very confused on this. Do I need to add SDKs for every ad network in AIR or simply change mediation settings in dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Are you mean https://github.com/monumentichb/Firebase-Admob-Mediation-ANE ?
Google Firebase Admob Mediation Ane provides as3 api for flex and flash developer to integrate admob,unityads,inmobi,chartboost,vunlge and gdt into adobe air ios and android app ,support banner Ad,Interstitial Ad,Native Express Ad and Video ,not need java or oc.Support banner,Intersitial,native express ads,Video